# Increase padding to the tooltip text in the activity tab

Tags: feature-request, design, tooltips, activity

In any Stack Exchange site in the [**Activity**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) tab, the tooltip text for the *REPUTATION* and *Top tag* (red circled in the screenshot) are not having enough padding compared with the other sections.

For the remaining section tooltip text are having enough padding. Can be the padding updated in those two sections?

Screenshot contains all the section's tooltip:

> [image]